# Illustrator: How do I prevent Pathfinder from creating paths with no fill and no stroke?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

In Illustrator, when I apply Pathfinder tools (like Trim, Merge) it generates invisible paths (paths with no fill and no stroke). I believe this only occurs with compound paths.

These "ghost" paths often adversely affect later operations. I know how to find and delete them, but it is an annoyance to have to do so every time I apply a Pathfinder effect.

Is there a way to prevent this?

I suspect it may be something in my configuration because I cannot find evidence of other people having the same problem (or I was just calling it the wrong thing while looking for an answer).

Answer (score 1):

Choose `Pathfinder Options` from the menu on the **Pathfinder Panel** and adjust the settings.

[image]

Beyond this, you just have to remember to remove unpainted things if they occur.

Comment: I already have both options selected. From the name, it appears that the second one only affects Divide and Outline (which I don't use, so I can't say for sure). I can remember to remove them, but I'm looking for a way to avoid having to do it repeatedly (if there is in fact  a way).

Comment: I don't think there's a way to be honest. I always just select same and delete after using Merge or something.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this doesn't actually prevent illustrator from creating them, but will help with removing them.

Object>Path>Cleanup will give you the option to delete all unpainted objects